# Python: What is the benefit of importing a particular module from package vs simply importing the whole package?

Tags: python, module, package

Hi I'm trying to learn python, when looking at examples sometimes I see a whole package simply imported, while other times a specific module within the package is imported. What is the advantage of this?

For example:

import face_detection

vs

from face_detection import model

The former seems better to me as then it would require you to be more explicit by needing to use face_detection.model every time you'd like to use the model module rather than being vague and simply calling module. Is it really just a code style thing?

Comment: speed and/or memory constraints, probably

Comment: @SuperStew No. using `import module` or `from module import function` doesn't affect performance and memory, it's the same.

Comment: @zaki98 isn't that why it was a nono to `from scipy import *` instead of listing what you need

Comment: @SuperStew no, that's bad practice because it can unexpectedly shadow names in the importing module.

Answer (score 1):

Here is good explanation: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/187471

Short answer - there is no such difference.